# what can filter a port on Fedora 19 besides router, firewall and selinux?

Tags: fedora, port, openvpn, nmap

I am trying to use seafile which seems very nice.

Unfortunately I have an issue that I fail to explain.

From my two fedora 19 machines, nmap says port 12001 is filtered on the
distant (say private) server I am trying to use (from my desktop, and from my laptop both from home and office).

However, port 12001 is open on the official server cloud.seafile.com from both machines. This seems to exclude some action of firewall or selinux.
Moreover, I have temporarily disabled both, without any change.

Even more puzzling, port 12001 is open on the distant private server if I use a
fedora 17 laptop, XP , or archlinux. This seems to exclude my router as a possible cause.

Any idea, advice, would be of great help.

Comment: Is that distant server connected through internet or LAN? Are there any differences in IP (public/local) between your Archlinux/XP/Fedora machines?

Comment: The distant server is connected via internet.
Both XP and Fedora 19 run on the same hardware, my desktop computer, so they share the same IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was well hidden, the culprit: openvpn.